# xhost command in script fails when executed by initctl

Tags: 14.04, permissions, root, xserver, restricted-access

For some reason, I have to execute `xhost +SI:localuser:root` to allow GUI for `root` user. I have put this command in a shell script, which will be executed at startup by `upstart`. When I execute this command or this script manually as a another user it works fine. But when this script executed by `upstart` this command doesn't works.

I also tried by executing this command as other than `root` user in script as

```
   sudo -H -s otheruser xhost +SI:localuser:root
```

This also doesn't works.

**How can I allow GUI to `root` user at system startup?**

*Thanks for your time!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"GUI for `root` user" is considered harmful*, but, here's an explanation of your problem:

`xhost` tells the X Server that it may/may not accept connections from other hosts.

When `upstart` runs your script, no user has logged in and started an X Server. Therefore, `xhost` has nobody to talk to.

You need to delay execution of your `xhost` command until after you've logged in. `xhost` also needs a definition of the `DISPLAY` environment variable (so it can find the X Server). `man X` shows the format of `DISPLAY`: `hostname:displaynumber.screennumber`.

Answer: You cannot run `xhost` through `upstart` - the context is not right.

- - `root` is all-powerful, and graphics programs don't show you all that they do.